# Any advantages to including recipient's name in email headers?

Tags: email, send, email-headers

Are there any reasons (Spam, etc.) to include the name in the To: headers instead of just omitting them and only using the address?

Answer (score 0):

No, it just looks pretty, that's mostly it.

When you're sending mail to multiple people it can be useful when some of the recipients' email addresses don't easily map to their names.

Answer (score 0):

It usually displays in your email client. If you leave it out, it simply displays `<example@test.com>` instead of `Example Test <example@test.com>`.

Im guessing it might be a factor for spam detection too (so adding the recipients name makes it more likely to show up in the inbox)